# Lex operators and escape sequences

Tags: lex

`+` is one of the [Lex operators](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno//CS447/Lectures/Lexical.html/node11.html), so if it is used as a text character, then it should be preceeded with the escape operator `\`. Therefore, why do these two yield the same results?

```
[a+b]   {  printf("%s", yytext);  }  // matches a, +, or b
[a\+b]  {  printf("%s", yytext);  }  // does same as above
```

Why doesn't the first line break the escape rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading down a few lines in the documentation link you provide, you will find:

> Within square brackets most operators are ignored...

("Ignored " is possibly not the best description; the characters are not *ignored*; they are simply not special. So a plus inside square brackets is just a plus.)